# Set Image border when item is selected in a listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I ve been playing with this for a while and I can't make it work. Basically, I have a listbox with an image and a label. What I'd like is to change the color of the border of the image if that item is selected (the listbox is set to multiple selection)

This is I have so far...

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBox_DataTemplate">
                  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="220"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

             <Border x:Name="thumbBorder"  BorderThickness="8"  
               CornerRadius="8">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">


                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isSelected, 
                                    ElementName=lb_images}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush 
                                              Value="SteelBlue"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isSelected, 
                                     ElementName=lb_images}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                                              Value="Yellow"/>
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>

                        </Style>

                    </Border.Style>

                <Image Width="170" Height="190" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
x:Name="thumb"/>
            </Border>
```

However, nothing happens when I select the item. IIm really stuck, so any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataTrigger should use a `RelativeSource` Binding to the ListBoxItem container element, and use the correct property path `IsSelected`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBox_DataTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="8">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That's awesome! It works great!
Thanks for your help.